# PostgreSQL 11.1 - stabilize partition pruning at execution time

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

We are evaluating PostgreSQL 11 for our production, trying to use partitions to ease vacuum work.

We have a system with 4251 updates per second, ~1000 delete per second and   ~3221 inserts per second and 1 billion transaction per day.

We are facing the problem that partition pruning is not working steadily with updates although we have:

1. part_key=value in our `where` clause
2. `enable_partition_pruning = 'on'`.

We understood that there is a new patch at 11, that is supposed to support ( Faster Partition Pruning + Partition Pruning at Execution Time)

How can we stable partition pruning? How to identify the reason when it does not work? What parameters affect it?

Comment: Any reason you are not using 11.2 which is the latest minor version for Postgres 11

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and provide one complete query where this happens, the complete `create table` statement (including the partition definitions) and the execution plans generated using **`explain (analyze, buffers)`** that shows both situations (with and without partition pruning) as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [edit] your question, do not post code in comments

Answer (score 1):

If you set `enable_partition_pruning` in PostgresSQL v11, it will not scan those partitions that can be excluded because of the `WHERE` conditions.

This will only work in cases where the optimizer or the executor can easily deduce the condition on the partitioning key. So you need to have a simple condition of the form `key <operator> <constant>` in your query, where `<operator>` is `=`, `<`, `>`, `<=` or `>=` and `<constant>` is constant for the duration of the query (e.g., does not contain any `VOLATILE` functions).

Please provide an example that describes what you mean with "does not work steadily", then it is possible to tell more.